# php Email Form: Send to multiple addresses and exclude data from input

Tags: php, forms, email

I've got an incredibly simple email contact form that I want A) the input in the form fields to be sent to multiple address, and B) some of that data to be excluded from all of the recipients except for one.

I've got part A solved; however, part B is proving to be difficult, as I am merely an intermediate web designer and am in no way a pro at coding. Find the source code below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "firstemail@email.com,secondemail@email.com,thirdemail@email.com";
$email_subject = "Your email subject line";

function died($error) {
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['business_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$business_name = $_POST['business_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Business Name: ".clean_string($business_name). "\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.


<?php

}
?>
```

So again, sending to multiple addresses works, but I'd essentially like to have the first email receive ALL the data from the form, and all the other email addresses to receive everything but the email address line in their emails.

Thank you!

Comment: As someone who constantly has his email address rejected because it's "invalid" I feel the need to point out that your regex to check email is **not** correct. Use `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` instead.

Comment: what patterns in your email usually cause rejection, alex?

Comment: @ManuelOtto Plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Explode the $email_to at ',', then iterate over the array to build the content and send.

```
foreach($aMails as $sMail) {
    if($sMail == 'important@example.com') {
        //do the content stuff here
    }
    @mail($sMail, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear (in case I manage to mangle this up), that snipped of code you wrote overwrites the $email_to line of code at the top of my code, correct? and then the "//do the content stuff here" means put all the stuff that should be included in the email to the one email I want to have receiving all the information?

Comment: "//do the content stuff here" means just do what's importent for the special email address. Of course you do not want to do everything again and again what you need for every content...